# Windows 7 patch kb4012212 / 5 not able to install ,"The Update is not applicable to your Computer"

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to install Windows 7 Pro x86 patch kb4012212 / 5 for Ransomware security But not able to install ,errors occurs of "The Update is not applicable to your Computer". So Please help me to install this patch file to my system. or Is their any other patch file require before this installation.

Comment: You have Service Pack 1 installed, correct?  Make sure you don't already have KB4012215 installed.

Comment: Also 4012212/5 are the march editions of the fix. So if you have the cumulative rollups of april or march installed those patches might be already included) Could you tell the me the file version of one of the affected files? C:\Windows\System32\drivers\mrxsmb10.sys e.g. should be 6.1.7601.23677 or higher if any of the patches fixing the security flaw would be installed)

Comment: @Syberdoor - KB4012215 is the cumulative rollup for March.  [KB4015549](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4015549) is the cumulative rollup for April.  The cumulative rollup for May as not been released yet.

Comment: @Ramhound The May rollup is [KB4019264](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4019264).However MS decided to drop the monthly name in favor of a year-month numerical scheme, so maybe that's why you did not find it. My guess is this is so that they are automatically ordered by newest first as long as they are alphabetically sorted but it is a little confusing imo.